# put is not working in express js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have POST and PUT that is referring to same FORM. when i click submit button only POST requesting is being processed( because both POST and PUT have got the same route name which is a action of FORM), How can I implement PUT ?

//App.js

```
app.post('/addClassified',routes().saveClassified);  -- POST
app.put('/addClassified',routes().updateClassified); -- PUT

app.get('/newClassified',function(req,res){
    res.render('newClassifieds'); //Rendering form
});
```

// newClassifieds.pug

```
// Method and action of FORM

form(method='POST' action='/addClassified')
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Save
```

//routes.js   ROUTES

// Save classified  -- POST

```
functions.saveClassified = function (req, res) {
     console.log(req.body.category);
};
```

// PUT -- Update classified

```
functions.updateClassified = function (req, res) {

};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send a put request from html form in express and node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765431/how-to-send-a-put-request-from-html-form-in-express-and-node)

Answer (score 4):

You must know that HTML5 allows only GET and POST in forms so if you have to implement PUT actions you could follow these steps:

How can I implement PUT?
1.-Install "method-override" npm package.
2.-You have to call in your app.js like this:

```
`var methodOverride = require("method-override");
app.use(methodOverride("_method"))`
```

3.-Add '_method=PUT' in your action form like this:

`form(method='POST' action='/addClassified/<%=thing._id%>?_method=PUT')`

let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 1):

1)Install method-override package
 **npm install method-override**
 require package in index.js
 \code

`var methodOverride = require("method-override");
      app.use(methodOverride("_method"))
      app.put("/edit",function(req,res){});`

\add _method=put in form of  like

```
 <form action="/edit/?_method=PUT" method="post" >
```